# TOR 10: An Error Occurred ‘try again’ Playback ID on YouTube

Tags: browsers

After updating to TOR 10 I've got "An Error Occurred ‘try again’ Playback ID on YouTube".
I tried many ways to solve it, nothing helped, but the downgrade to the previous version.

Comment: For bug reports, you should make an issue on the https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser.

Comment: I have same issue. it works fine on previous version.

Comment: i have the exact same issue. going on the youtube website itself works fine, but when i try to play any video it then displays that message

Comment: I have the exact same issue watching YouTube videos in Tor Browser 10.0 on Windows. However, watching YouTube in Tor Browser 10.0 works fine on Linux. I don't know what causes the issue.

Comment: Hi everyone, unless you have a solution, please upvote this post rather than writing an answer, otherwise it looks like this issue is already solved because it has so many answers. The bug is being tracked at https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40140.

Answer (score 2):

https://blog.torproject.org/new-release-tor-browser-100

> Update 1700 UTC 2020-09-24: After investigating the error seen by Windows users while playing videos on Youtube, a user helped us identify the cause. Until this is fixed in an upcoming release, a workaround is setting media.rdd-opus.enabled as false in about:config.